# Symlink to simulate /storage/extSdCard in Android 6.0

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, external-sd, linux

So recently, I started using Android 6.0, and one of the first things I noticed was that the external SD card was no longer mounted under `/storage/extSdCard` anymore; instead, it was mounted under a folder named after the Volume ID in `/storage`, meaning that several of my applications that originally used the `/storage/extSdCard` path could not anymore.

I was curious as to whether it's possible for me to create a symlink in storage to the new path named `/storage/extSdCard` so that those applications can still use it, but when I tried using `ln -s /storage/some-volume-id /storage/extSdCard` to create the link, though, the result ended up being only visible and usable as the root user.

I checked the permissions which saw full `rwx` permissions for all, tried changing the group to match the others, tried the symlink switch on the commands, and tried remounting filesystems read/write, but the link still doesn't work for any of the apps or non-superusers.

I'm still relatively new to this, so is there anything I'm overlooking that somehow keeps the link from showing up?

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgrade to 6.0 over-the-air? You may need to flash a fresh installation if you intend on keeping your phone unrooted. I've never heard of anyone being able to create symlinks/modify mount points/etc. without root. But maybe someone will come along here who knows more than I do.